# How can i rewrite a image file name to query string via rewrite rules in Apache

Tags: apache

I am trying to create a php script that will check if a image is local and if not retrieve it from remote site. I want the user to call the image like this.

> http://media.myimage.org/media/2AF97A30-42F7-4E08-8BF6-020316D6F161.jpg

To make it work i need to create a rule that will rewrite the url to the following request

> http://media.myimage.org/media/image.php?id=2AF97A30-42F7-4E08-8BF6-020316D6F161

i tried multiple ways and tested them via https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but they all fail with
rule was not meet

i want to take my regexpr  '/([{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?)(.jpg)/m'
and if it is meet then translate it to 'image.php?id=${1}' if not i want to redirect to a 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

With some more research I was able to solve my issue. Not sure its the best way but it works. If anyone has a recommendation to improve I am all ears.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?+).(jpg|png|gif)$ /madia/image.php?id=$1&format=$3 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /images/404.php?image=$1 [L]
```

The above will accept any image request as long as the image name is a valid guid and the file has the extension of jpg or png or gif. If this Rewrite rule is hit we will exit, if not we will do the 404 rewrite.